# How to determine remote IP address from JAX-RS resource?

Tags: glassfish, jax-rs, grizzly

I have the following JAX-RS resource running in Grizzly HTTP server:

```
@Path("/board")
public class BoardResource {

    @POST
    @Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    public void login(@FormParam("email") String email, @FormParam("password") String password,
            @HeaderParam("user-agent") String userAgent) {
        // how to determine remote IP address here?
    }
}
```

How can I determine remote IP address inside login() handler?

Thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since right now this is not [possible](https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-473) to access remote IP information from Grizzly context, I've implemented this dirty hack:

First, I've added new dependency injection binder to my application, which will bind java.net.SocketAddress instance to one containing request origin IP:

```
package test;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.SocketAddress;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Provider;
import org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.Request;
import org.glassfish.hk2.api.Factory;
import org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder;
import org.glassfish.jersey.internal.PropertiesDelegate;
import org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScoped;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerRequest;

public class RemoteAddrBinder extends AbstractBinder {

    private static class RemoteAddrProviderFactory implements Factory<SocketAddress> {
        @Inject
        private Provider<ContainerRequest> request;

        @Override
        public SocketAddress provide() {
            ContainerRequest containerRequest = request.get();
            PropertiesDelegate delegate = containerRequest.getPropertiesDelegate();
            try {
                Field requestField = delegate.getClass().getDeclaredField("request");
                requestField.setAccessible(true);
                Request grizzlyRequest = (Request) requestField.get(delegate);
                return new InetSocketAddress(grizzlyRequest.getRemoteAddr(), grizzlyRequest.getRemotePort());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void dispose(SocketAddress instance) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure() {        bindFactory(RemoteAddrProviderFactory.class).to(SocketAddress.class).in(RequestScoped.class);
    }
}
```

Then, I've registered this binder in the application:

```
application.register(new RemoteAddrBinder());
```

Now, SocketAddress can be injected into any JAX-RS method:

```
@GET
@Path("test")
public Response test(@Context SocketAddress remoteAddr) {
    return Response.ok("Your IP is: " + ((InetSocketAddress) remoteAddr).getAddress().getHostAddress()).build();
}
```

Hope this helps someone :)

Answer (score 2):

The solution by spektom no longer works on the latest versions. Fortunately now a nicer solution exists, adding the following to your method parameters:

```
@Context org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.Request req
```

Which in your case would look like this:

```
@Path("/board")
public class BoardResource {

    @POST
    @Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    public void login(@Context Request req, @FormParam("email") String email, @FormParam("password") String password,
            @HeaderParam("user-agent") String userAgent) {
        // remote IP address
        System.out.println(req.getRemoteAddr());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As per developers explanations - Grizzly is not fully compliant to JAX-RS 2.0 so there will be no official contexts injections/wrapping. See [Jersey Bug-1960](https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-1960)
Applicable for Jersey + Grizzly version 2.7+

Luckily there is a way to inject Grizzly request/response objects. Kind of tricky but works
Code sample provided in one of Jersey's unit tests. See [Jersey container test](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/cf236e5ae2820db67a9581a8eece53d01a412cae/tests/e2e/src/test/java/org/glassfish/jersey/tests/e2e/container/Jersey2462Test.java#L113)

So code fragment will be:

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Provider;

public someclass {
    @Inject
    private Provider<Request> grizzlyRequestProvider;

    public void method() {
         if (grizzlyRequestProvider != null) {
            Request httpRequest = grizzlyRequestProvider.get();

            // Extract what you need
            String remoteAddress = httpRequest.getRemoteAddr();
         }
    }
}
```

Works fine both for filters and service methods

Comment: Works great (2.22.2) but you need to ensure you dont get import issues with javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider and javax.inject.Provider

Answer (score 1):

You should add an extra argument to that method of type [`HttpServletRequest`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) and which you put the `@Context` annotation on. You can then use that argument's [`getRemoteAddr()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getRemoteAddr%28%29) method to get what you want.

```java
@Path("/board")
public class BoardResource {
    @POST
    @Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    public void login(@FormParam("email") String email,
            @FormParam("password") String password,
            @HeaderParam("user-agent") String userAgent,
            @Context HttpServletRequest request) {
        String remoteIP = request.getRemoteAddr();
        // ...
    }
}
```

Yes, it's a `String`…

Comment: But I don't have HttpServletRequest class in my classpath. Maybe this is because I use Grizzly HTTP server?

Comment: Really? The [javadoc I find](http://grizzly.java.net/nonav/docs/2.0/apidocs/index.html) for Grizzly indicates that the classes are quite thoroughly related to the servlet classes, so it's got to be available at runtime (or Grizzly _wouldn't_ work). I guess that your build-time classpath is incomplete…

Comment: I tried adding servlet API to my build-time classpath, but this variable is not injected in the runtime - I get null.